# I'm trying to bind functionality to a button, but something is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, es6-class

I wish my buttons would invoke the functions that bound to them. Can someone explain me what went wrong here? I've bound functionality to some `<button>` elements I injected with Javascript but it looks like `user.method` in line 41 is returning `undefined`.

http://codepen.io/ueeieei/pen/KNQbXO?editors=0011

```js
var $container = $('.container');

class User {
  constructor(name, age, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.type = type;
  }

  sing() {
    alert("singing");
    console.log("singing");
  }

  sleep() {
    alert("sleeping");
    console.log("sleeping");
  }

  collectMethods() {
    var methodNames = {
      sing: "Sing",
      sleep: "Sleep"
    };

    return methodNames;
  }
}

function createButton(user) {
  var methodNames = user.collectMethods();

  for (var method in methodNames) {
    var $btn = $('<button>' + methodNames[method] + '</button>');
    $btn.bind("click", user.method);
    $container.append($btn);
  };
}

var udi = new User("Udi", 97.2, "In-Process");
var serj = new User("Serge", "30ish", "musico-programmer")

createButton(udi);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: white;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: There's no excuse for profanity here. This is a site for all ages.

Comment: first of all `As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method` so you better use .on

Comment: second of all, user dont have a field called `method`, this is very basic javascript, if you want to access objects property with a variable you should do user[method];

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because in your event handler, `method` is a variable. To access a property of an object through storing its name in a variable, you have to use bracket notation. For example, `user[method]` instead of `user.method`.

Also note that `bind()` was deprecated a long time ago. You should be using `on()` instead. You should also double check the version of jQuery you're using and update it as necessary. I'd suggest upgrading to 1.12 at the very least.

Here's a working version of your code:

```js
var $container = $('.container');

class User {
  constructor(name, age, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.type = type;
  }

  sing() {
    alert("singing");
    console.log("singing");
  }

  sleep() {
    alert("sleeping");
    console.log("sleeping");
  }

  collectMethods() {
    var methodNames = {
      sing: "Sing",
      sleep: "Sleep"
    };

    return methodNames;
  }
}

function createButton(user) {
  var methodNames = user.collectMethods();

  for (var method in methodNames) {
    var $btn = $('<button>' + methodNames[method] + '</button>');
    $btn.on("click", user[method]); // this is the line which was fixed
    $container.append($btn);
  };
}

var udi = new User("Udi", 97.2, "In-Process");
var serj = new User("Serge", "30ish", "musico-programmer")

createButton(udi);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: white;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- content here -->
</div>
```